# WPF Datagrid. Get the values of each cell of the selected row

Tags: wpf, wpftoolkit, wpfdatagrid

I'm using the WPF toolkit DataGrid.

How can I get the values of the cells of the selected rows?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In WPF rows represent objects in a list and columns are object's properties.

It depends on what DataGrid.ItemsSource is.If your ItemSource is an array of BindedClass you could get selected object by:

```
BoundClass bc = (BoundClass)dataGridControl.SelectedItem;
var prop1 = bc.Prop1;
var prop2 = bc.Prop2;
```

Comment: Ok, I got it. The problem was that I retrieve the info from the DB using Linq, and I did it using anonymous types. But you gave me the clue to find my mistake explaining me how the datagrid works. Thanks!