# How to Find Wpf DataGrid Row

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I'm making a Wpf Application.  My problem is that I'm using a `DataGrid` to show tabular data.  How can I find the related row of my datatable when I click the listview Selected Cell?

Comment: Do you want the data item bound to the row, or the physical row itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for this? [WPF Datagrid set selected row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1976087/wpf-datagrid-set-selected-row)

[WPF Datagrid. Get the values of each cell of the selected row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1570929/wpf-datagrid-get-the-values-of-each-cell-of-the-selected-row)